# Windows 2003 TS sessions freeze one second after logging in

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services

We have a Windows 2003 TS server, and when I log in 90% of the time the session immediately freezes after about a second. The mouse pointer appears to move, but windows are sometimes partially drawn, nothing updates, and I cannot click on anything. Disconnecting the session and re-connecting provides another one second of access, but no more.

If I log on to the box as the local administrator user and kill my session, I can then log in again and get a few minutes use, but the problem always returns after a while.

The box is connected to an NT domain. Also, I am not a Windows administrator, although I do have admin access to the box, I am just a reasonably competent user.

James

Comment: Since you're the admin to the box, can you provide logs or things from event viewer, perfmon, task manager, anything?